# TiddlyWiki5 and highlight.js - How to change style / theme of syntax highlighting?

Tags: themes, highlight, highlight.js, tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

I am using TiddlyWiki version 5.1.13. I have added the highlight plugin (version 5.1.13) which uses highlight.js (version 8.8.0).

In a tiddler I successfully highlight XML like this:

````
```xml
  <html>
    <body>
    </body>
  </html>
```
````

How can I change the highlight style / theme to one of highlight.js various styles? ([Highlight.js styles](https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/))

Comment: BTW, this is exactly the way to highlight code in SO as well. *wink*

Answer (score 26):

When you add Highlight.js to your site's directory, it contains a directory called `styles`. Inside that directory you have styles for all the themes available with Highlight.js.

To switch to a different theme, simply switch this line

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/styles/default.css">`

to something like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/styles/pick-theme-name-here.css">`

Answer (score 6):

Here is the URL to the styles directory in the 
[highlight.js repo](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/tree/master/src/styles).

I found it useful to locate the name of the `Vs 2015` theme which isn't `vs-2015` but rather `vs2015`.

I'm importing the styles from a CDN:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.0.3/styles/default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.0.3/styles/vs2015.min.css">
```

Also, for the record, Vs 2015 is very similar to VS Code's `Dark+ (default dark)` theme. That's the default theme that ships with VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

The MadPhysicist's answer below is not as right as it can be. I'm using the highlight.js 10.3.1 version and the style css is available only in .min on cdnjs. So you must put pick-theme-name-here.min.css and not pick-theme-name-here.js

Ex :

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.3.1/styles/solarized-light.css

=> 404

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.3.1/styles/solarized-light.min.css

=> available

Comment: This reads more like a problem description than an answer. Could you elaborate how this helps to solve the described problem?

Comment: You're right, but I didn't really know where to put this. The MadPhysicist's answer is not right as you must put pick-theme-name-here.min.css and not pick-theme-name-here.js. May be I should only comment his post, and not create an answer.

Comment: Either do that to provide helpful feedback there or add all information and context here (with or without contrasting to the other answer) to make a complete competitive answer.

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand what you explained : with my editing, is my answer correct now ?

Comment: Looks fine now.